# After today's Windows 10 update, System is periodically using 5% CPU

Tags: windows, windows-10

Just wondering if anyone else has noticed that, after the 2022-03 updates to Windows 10, System occasionally uses ~5% CPU for a few minutes.

Comment: What is wrong with 5% CPU?  My computers run about 5% CPU more than 95% of the time and work fine.

Comment: Not the entire computer, just the System process.

Comment: Even just System at 5% should not present any issue. My processes vary a lot by process even at low CPU.